# Allocation of data through a list of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, memory, reference

I'm trying to read the data of several objects from a file. The reading itself works fine, but I'm having trouble with writing the data into a `std::list<MyObject*>`. I tried a couple of things but it always ends with the application crashing after printing some stuff, which I think is random memory content. Below you can find the current version. I also tried Iterators but that didn't work either.
Here's what happens in the calling method:

```
    PAProject proj2 = PAProject();
    proj2.projectName = "myfirstOne";

    PaFigureLoader::loadFigures(&proj2);

    std::list<PAFigure*>::iterator figIterator;
    for(figIterator = proj2.figures.begin();
            figIterator != (proj2.figures.end());
            figIterator++) {
        PAFigure* fig = *figIterator;
        if(fig->firstname.empty()) {
            std::cout << "Nothing to see here\n";
            break;
        } else {
            std::cout << fig->firstname << "\n";
        }
    }
```

The list is `std::list<PAFigure*> figures`

Method causing all the trouble:

```
static void loadFigures(PAProject *project)
{
        //open input stream
    fs::ifstream ifstream(filename);
    std::string input;
    ifstream >> input;
    PAFigure * fig;

    //keep a string for all the splitting:
    std::string result;

    //define regexs
    std::regex reg1 ("(<firstname>)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(</firstname>)");
    std::regex reg2 ("(<lastname>)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(</lastname>)");

    //iterate through file to find all figures
    while(input.compare("</allfigures>") != 0) {

        //do the figure-loading stuff
        if(input.compare("<figure>")==0) {
            PAFigure newFigure = PAFigure();
            project->figures.push_front(&newFigure);
            fig = &newFigure;
        }

        //find contents
        if(input.find("<firstname>")!= std::string::npos) {
            std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), input.begin(), input.end(), reg1, "$2");
            fig->firstname = result;
            result.erase();
            std::cout << fig->firstname << " is firstname\n";
        }
        if(input.find("<lastname>")!= std::string::npos) {
            std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), input.begin(), input.end(), reg2, "$2");
            fig->lastname = result;
            result.erase();
        }

        //read next line
        ifstream >> input;
    }
    PAFigure * figtest = project->figures.back();
    std::cout << figtest->firstname << " last element\n";

    figtest = project->figures.front();
    std::cout << figtest->firstname << " first element\n";
}
```

Here's the output:

```
 died
Anna is firstname
 died
Dorian is firstname
Dorian last element
Dorian first element
Dorian died
Anna died
```

I added

```
PAFigure::~PAFigure()
{
   std::cout << this->firstname << " died\n";

}
```

because I had that weird feeling that my elements were just gone, and apparently the `PAFigure newFigure = PAFigure()` does infact never get a firstname.

I admit that my coding experience in C++ and especially with pointer/references is very... basic. I have no idea how to solve this, not even talking about solving it in an elegant way.

Comment: Invest in learning breakpoint/step debugging... You will find exactly what's happening.

Comment: @krOoze I'm familiar with breakpoints and debugging, however that wouldn't be as convenient to post and I KNEW what was wrong, I just couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use pointer rather than reference.

Here is what's wrong:

```
PAFigure newFigure = PAFigure();
```

You should use a pointer to push, rather than reference.

```
PAFigure *newFigure = new PAFigure();
project->figures.push_front(newFigure);
// and create another object too.
PAFigure *fig = new PAFigure();
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job.